# hitting: 'pulumi new' error: cloning templates repo: reference not found

Tags: pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

Following get started [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/get-started/) at pulumi, After setting up the service account at google cloud, trying to run **pulumi new**, it asked for login on pulumi which was successful, and then it throw an **error: cloning templates repo: reference not found**. Already tried reinstalling the pulumi via choco but the error is still there.
Already open an issue on github: [github issue](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/12277)

Comment: In case any future Googlers run into this issue, it looks like the solution was to delete the `.pulumi/templates` directory and re-run `pulumi new`.